# Download large video files with pause and resume and background fetch in ios.?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, download

How to Download a large video file in ios with the capability to download the file when the app is in background and also with pause and resume features.

I Have used TCBLobDownload manager , it can pause and resume the downloading but unable to download in background .

Tried AFNetworking Download task but can't achieve the required task.

so how to achieve the above pause+resume+background fetch.?

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial which downloads file in background.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595